# Viewing most recently published document version while document is being updated

Tags: document

Is it possible for the most recent published/approved version of a document to be available for viewing while the document is under revision and approval.

I'm working with a customer that has line-side work instructions for operators. The Operators need the most current published/approved document version visible on the screen while they work.

If the document needs updating, is it possible for the last published/approved version of the document to still be available for viewing if the document goes into revision/edit mode (minor revision vs. major revision - content approval) or will the document be invisible until such time as it is approved once again?

Answer (score 0):

You are describing exactly how SharePoint document publishing/versioning works.  Assuming your operators only have read permissions to the library where the document resides and you are using the default versioning settings, these users will see only the major versions that are published and approved.  If that same document is revised (a minor version created) the operators will not see that until it is once again published and approved.

This post describes it well and includes screenshots:
http://blog.fpweb.net/sharepoint-version-control-content-approval

Comment: Hello - Yes, I believe I understand the way SharePoint document publishing / versioning works ...  The challenge:  The Operators need to be able to see the most recently "approved and published" version of the work instruction - all the time.  Many/most versioning systems I am aware of do not remove the current published version from use while a subsequent draft is being proposed.  If it takes 6 weeks until the next approval, the current document becomes useless.  I'm beginning to surmise the document will need to be updated in another location then over write to the current published version.

Comment: Perhaps I'm not clear. Let's say that your team just published and approved major version 7.0. Then that is what operators see. If your editing team then begins to work on versions 7.1, 7.2... 7.45, etc. the operators won't see these until version major version 8.0 is published and approved.  My suggestion is to try it out so you can see the exact behavior from readers and editor/approved angles.